# How can I find string with regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, search, expression

I have html string like that for example

```
<td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">John 23</td>
```

I want to find "John 23" between `'<td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">'` and `'</td>'`

I want to find with Regular Expressions in python

How can I do it?

Comment: Why don't you use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8164958)

Comment: I recommend you to check [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: I don't have any idea about BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? This is far too broad/vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML. Regex is the wrong tool; it works fine for this example but wouldn't scale well to a full document.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">John 23</td>'
>>> BeautifulSoup(html).find("td").text
'John 23'
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The BeautifulSoup is so perfect library.